# Postgis - Split linestring between point A and B

Tags: postgis, linestring

I need to find the different trajectories between point A and B. In the image is possible to see 2 differents trajectories.
The way i use to calculate them is: Found the min time and the max time (in a specific date), and make a linestring with the points between this two times.
The problem is that the min and max are near one of the other and the result is only one linestring.
My problem now is split the line string, and stay with different trajectories for example 1 and 2 (image), because what i want is the different trajectories between A and B like image.

[image]

Way to found nearest points of A and B

> ```
> SELECT *
> from tese.cars 
> WHERE (((
>
>   st_dwithin(
>           (SELECT geom
>           FROM tese.cars
>           WHERE (carid = 1 AND rdate = 190101 AND rtime = 85000)) -- Point A
>   , geom, 20))
>   OR
>   st_dwithin(
>           (SELECT geom
>           FROM tese.cars
>           WHERE (carid = 2 AND rdate = 120101 AND rtime = 153804)) -- Point B
>       , geom, 20))
>       )
> ```

Way to found Points between A and B

> ```
> INSERT INTO tese.cars2
> SELECT t.*
> FROM tese.cars as t
> INNER JOIN tese.pontosAB as tt
> ON    t.carid=tt.carid 
>       AND 
>   t.rdate=tt.rdate 
>       AND 
>           (   
>           t.rtime > (SELECT min(rtime) from tese.pontosAB where carid=t.carid and rdate=t.rdate) 
>               AND 
>           t.rtime < (SELECT max(rtime) from tese.pontosAB where carid=t.carid and rdate=t.rdate)
>           )
> ```

Point to LineString

> ```
> SELECT rdate, min(rtime), max(rtime), st_makeline(geom)
> FROM tese.cars2
> group by rdate
> ```

Comment: It isn't very clear how you generate the linestrings from min/max time. What Postgis function are you using?

Comment: I'm using gps points of differents cars in denmark. I choose 2 randmon points to find the different trajectories betweens them. 
Linestrings are results of points of one or more trajectories.

1º I select the points nearest A and B in order to find differnt trajectories..

2º I select the points between A and B, through the time (min and max) 

3º Convert de different trajectories (points) to a linestring..

If you can help me by skype, please add me, fabiombpereira